# Lebesgue integral involving distance function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, whose complement has finite measure, and let $\delta(x)$ denote the distance from $x$ to $F$, that is $$\delta(x)=d(x,F)=\inf\{ | x -y | : y \in F \}\,\,\,$$

Consider $$I(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\delta(y)}{ |x-y|^2} dy$$

Show that $I(x) < \infty$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ I actually found the solution to this problem but I do not fully understand it.

$$ \int_{F} I(x) dx = \int_{F} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy dx = 
\int_{F} \int_{\mathbb{F^c}} \frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2} dy dx
$$

Let us assume everything is measurable so we can use Tonelli's theorem to sway the limits of integration.

Then $$ \int_{F^c} \delta(y) \int_{F} \frac{1}{|x-y|^2} dx dy$$

$\textbf{This is the part where I am a bit lost...}$

Observe that $$ F \subset \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-y| \ge \delta(y)$$

What was the motivation for seeing this??

Then, $$ \int_{F} \frac{1}{|x-y|^2} dx \le 2 \int_{\delta(y)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}= \frac{2}{\delta(y)}$$

The line above is particularly confusing to me. Can anyone clarify the reasoning behind using $\delta(y)$ in the limit of the integral ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclusion $F\subset\{x:|x-y|\geq \delta(y)\}$ (note that $y\in F^c$) follows from
$$(\forall x\in F)\qquad |x-y|\geq \inf_{z\in F}|z-y|=\delta(y),$$
hence
$$\int_F \frac1{|x-y|^2} dx \leq \int_{\{x:|x-y|\geq \delta(y)\}} \frac1{|x-y|^2}dx. $$
Let $z:=|x-y|$. Note that for any $s>0$, $x>y$ such that $z=x-y=s$, there exists also a unique $x'<y$ such that $|x'-y|=s$. 
Let us consider $x>y$, hence $dz=d(x-y)=dx$, and
$$\int_{\{x:|x-y|\geq \delta(y)\}} \frac1{|x-y|^2}dx \leq 2 \int_{\delta(y)}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{z^2} dz .$$
The factor 2 arises exactly because we found 
for any $s>0$, $x>y$ such that $z=x-y=s$, there exists also a unique $x'<y$ such that $|x'-y|=s$.